# how to convert base 64 encoded public key (.pem) to bytearray?

Tags: openssl

I need to convert a Base 64 encoded public key file in .pem format to byte array using openssl.

Need to convert public key from the below format:

```
----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxl4aRnRMBB9GZrNgy6sy
seyIA3Ek3a1xg0b8gKrCSgnSjH+lqtBGwtzKqM020piE1q0YrzGpfQxNJ8HPRc0F
OlII7VKuCFGqEuLH2+kFJPUUdRqBr0iN/D8ADp9rLEL2Q4F7qM1t0z0IW6zD

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

to  this format:

```
48, -127, -97, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13,...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed -e '/----.*PUBLIC KEY----\|^[[:space:]]*$/d' praj.pem | 
    base64 -d | 
    hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02d, "' ; echo
```

This uses `sed` to remove the blank lines and lines containing the BEGIN and END markers for the public key, then pipes that into `base64 -d` to decode it, and then pipes that into `hexdump` with a custom format to print the bytes as comma-and-space separated decimal numbers.
Finally `echo` is used to make sure the output finishes with a newline (`\n`).

Output:

```
48, -126, 01, 34, 48, 13, 06, 09, 42, -122, 72, -122, -9, 13, 01, 01, 01, 05, ...
```

Comment: on macOS, you need a -D or --decode, for the Base64 decode part of the command..